# Version solving failed with intl_translation ^0.19.0

Tags: flutter, dart

```bash
% flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (1.5s)
Note: meta is pinned to version 1.10.0 by flutter_localizations from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.


Because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on meta 1.10.0 and analyzer >=6.3.0 depends on meta ^1.11.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with analyzer >=6.3.0.
And because every version of member_end from path depends on intl_translation ^0.19.0 which depends on analyzer ^6.3.0, flutter_localizations from sdk is incompatible with member_end from path.
So, because member_end_app depends on both flutter_localizations from sdk and member_end from path, version solving failed.
```

```bash
% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on macOS 12.7.1 21G920 darwin-x64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

intl_translation needs analyzer >= 6.3.0, analyzer needs meta 1.11.0, but flutter_localizations pin meta to version 1.10.0, on my god.
What should I do? I need both of intl_translation and flutter_localizations.

This is my pubspec.yaml file, `member_end` and `member_end_flutter` are from path.

```yaml
name: member_end_app
description: "flutter front member end application base."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  member_end:
    path: ../member_end
  member_end_flutter:
    path: ../member_end_flutter
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  riverpod: ^2.4.9
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.3


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  go_router: ^13.0.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.6.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
  build_runner: ^2.4.7
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  riverpod_generator: ^2.3.9
  custom_lint: ^0.5.7
  riverpod_lint: ^2.3.7
  go_router_builder: ^2.4.1
  build_verify: ^3.1.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets/images/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: What does you package.yaml look like?

Comment: @puelo Hi, I've updated the question, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your pubspec.yaml file.
2. Locate the meta dependency and change it to a version that is compatible with both flutter_localizations and analyzer. For example:

yaml

dependencies:
meta: ^1.11.0

3. This sets the minimum version to 1.11.0, which should satisfy the requirement of both flutter_localizations and analyzer.
4. Save the changes to the pubspec.yaml file.
5. Run flutter pub get again:

bash

flutter pub get

Comment: Thks, override meta dependency that works for me
dependency_overrides:
  meta: ^1.11.0